# IIs Applicationpool running on 4.0 instead of 2.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, configuration, windows-server-2008

I have a iis server with displaying a root website and applicationpool setup to run on runtime 2.0. still the application pool uses asp.net 4.0 to compile and display the website. we found this by creating an empty website only requesting the .net runtime and configuration path. if i configure the website and application pool exacly the same on a differend server the website runs in 2.0 mode.

I have 2 windows 2008 R2 Service pack 1 servers with IIS 7.5. 
the following .net versions are installed on both servers 2.0 3.5 4.0 4.5.
on both servers aspnet regiis shows the following:

```
aspnet_regiis -lv
2.0.50727.0             C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.5072\aspnet_isapi.dll
4.0.30319.0             C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.3031\aspnet_isapi.dll
2.0.50727.0             C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll
4.0.30319.0             C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
```

i have run aspnet_regiis -i on the server not willing to run 2.0
we have compaired almost every iis setting but could not find any differences. is there anybody who nows how to make iis run asp.net 2.0 again?

Steps taken:

1. did a file compare on applicationHost.config and made not working config file as much as possible same to working file
2. Compared all found documented registry settings for iis and asp.net
3. reregistered asp.net 2.0 and 4.0
4. Uninstalled .net 4.5.1(this made the 2.0 application work) and installed it again(2.0 applications run under 4.0 again)

Differences found:
Change .Net Framework version om server configuration in iis is on v4.0.30319 on not working version. on working version this is v2.0.50727. changing this to v2.0.50727 will be undone after iisreset.

edit:
just to showing the basic configuration:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I checked it 2 times and let a buddy check it just to be sure. we target the right application pool. and the application pool targets v2.0

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have the same on a Windows 2008 R2 virtual machine where an app should have been downgraded from v4.0 to v2.0.

Comment: no solution found yet. still searching

Comment: I'm facing the same issue but the other way around, I have an application on a .Net 4 apppool running as a 2.0 app.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Right click on webapplication in IIS and check application pool used 
here framework version must be v2.0 that is .NET2.0

Comment: This answer is nonsense. The point is that the framework version is set to v2.0 (see first screenshot of the question) and still the site is using v4.0.